# Express the integral as an equivalent integral.

Tags: calculus

> To Find:Express the integral as an equivalent integral in which the z-integration is performed first, the y-integration second and the x-integration last:

$$\int_0^3\int_0^{(9-z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\int_0^{(9-y^2-z^2)^\frac{1}{2}}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

$$R=\left \{ (x,y,z):0\le y \le (9-z^2)^\frac{1}{2},  0 \le z \le 3, 0 \le x \le (9-y^2-z^2)^\frac{1}{2} \right \}$$

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=9$$

$$x=0, y=0, z=0$$

$$R=\left \{(x,y,z): 0 \le x \le3, 0 \le y \le (9-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}, 0 \le z \le (9-x^2-y^2)^\frac{1}{2}  \right \}$$
But where to from here?

$$\int_0^3\int_0^{(9-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\int_0^{(9-x^2-y^2)^\frac{1}{2}}f(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx$$